# Transforming very long C++ string literals to meet max line length policy

Tags: c++, code-formatting

I am working with old C++ that has very long string literals.

My employer recently adopted a policy limiting line length when checking in modified code, and some of these strings are longer than the maximum line length.

Where there are not too many I can break the strings by hand, but today I am faced with a file containing ~1,700 strings that exceed the line length limit.

As we all know, C++ concatenates adjacent string literals and as an example my approach has been to turn

```
const char * pStr = "0123456789ABCDEF1123456789ABCDEF ... F123456789ABCDEF";
```

into:

```
const char * pStr = "0123456789ABCDEF"
                    "1123456789ABCDEF"
                    "2123456789ABCDEF"
                    // and more rows until finally
                    "F123456789ABCDEF";
```

It's going to take me a long time to process the file with ~1,700 string literals that exceed the line length limit, so I'm looking for guidance as to how to address this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you just breaking the `"long string"` into `"long " "string"`? What OS?

Comment: Don't have a strong preference.
Have been doing
"Very " 
"long, "
"long, "
"string."
(But each line is ~120 chars)

It's windows.  I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: you can write a script to transform the text of the cpp file, but it still sounds like a tedious manual process.

Comment: [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) can split those strings for you.

Comment: Thanks @Kenny I had thought about it, but the source files are ridiculously long, and I am worried about messing up things that are not actual strings (for example, strings in comments).  I'm hoping someone else has already done it and can just share their method.

Comment: clang-format knows the difference between comments and strings.  Why don't you try it out, and then examine the diffs before committing if you're worried?

Comment: Thanks @paddy, I'm going to do that.  Sounds like the consensus way to go.

Comment: I really recommend clang-format. It's the correct tool for the job (and could fix many other formatting issues). Configuration can be a bit long-winded, but there are online tools to test and create a config file for clang-format

Comment: I'd write a python script to do the work.

Comment: Thanks @Simon, yep, turns out that clang-format 5 has been built into Visual Studio since version 15.7.  I didn't know.  There is also a plug-in that claims to be version 9 compatible.  I've borrowed a .clang-format file from a friend, and 20,000 lines of SQL test strings are neatly formatted, with none over the length limit.
Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks @nada - it turns out that clang-format does the job.  I like Python but i don't think I could write a script to do the job as well as clang-format has.

Comment: @PeterDu https://www.clangpowertools.com/ is a really excellent VS extension, if you want to leverage clang-format and clang-tidy (which I also highly recommend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of @botje, @paddy and @simon I used clang-format, and it did exactly what I needed it to do.  Note that Visual Studio 15.7 comes with clang-format version 5 already built in.  Visual Studio 15.9 has clang-format version 6.  There is an extension for Visual Studio that is clang-format version 9.

The key lines in the .clang-format file are:

```
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:         119
```